# Enter mode is getting changed in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In `CKEditor` I wants to differentiate between pasted content and the content added by the user. So, on `paste` event of ckeditor I am changing the `p` tags of copied content to `div` so that all new paragraphs are represented by `div` tags for copied code. Below is the code.

```
editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
     evt.data.dataValue = data.replace(/(<p)/igm, '<div').replace(/<\/p>/igm, '</div>');
});
```

This works fine but after doing this when I am pressing enter and trying add any new content `ckeditor` is adding a new `div` tag to wrap the content whereas I have this declaration present in my config

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

I tried to change the enter mode in after paste event but didn't helped.

```
editor.on('afterPaste', function(evt) {
    editor.setActiveEnterMode(null);
});
```

Any suggesttions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not mix `<div>`s with paragraphs. The content inside the editor should be clean and by making it inconsistent you make it messy. This may cause more issues in the future.
2. Try the [`config.forceEnterMode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-forceEnterMode) option. By default CKEditor uses the block that you're currently in (to be consistent). With this option you are forcing it to use the block from the enter mode.

Comment: Great suggestion, I have changed my implementation.